# Finding arithmetic sequence first term

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I've got a question regarding a mathematical problem I've been trying to solve.

How can I find the first term and the common rule of this arithmetic sequence with the following info:

The common difference ($d$) = $11$

The sum of the first 40 terms of the sequence = $8700$

So, how can I find the first term and the common rule of this sequence.

I hope I can get some help because I've been struggling trying to solve this problem for quite a while.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  If the starting term were $0$, the sum of $40$ terms would be eleven times the sum of the numbers from $0$ to $39$.  Can you do that?  Then increasing the starting term by $1$ increases all the terms by $1$ and therefore the sum by $40$.

Comment: Still couldn't quite get the correct answer. Is there any way to make an equation and solve it that way?

Comment: Yes there is.  Your series is $a, a+1, a+2 \ldots, a+39$  Adding them up gives $40a+\sum_{i=0}^{39}i=8700$  That is why I asked if you could do the last sum.

Comment: Now that you have changed the difference, your series is $a, a+11, a+22, \ldots a+429$.  Adding them up gives $40a+11\sum_{i=0}^{39}=8700$

Comment: Ah, got it now. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since common difference is $11$, we let the first term be $x$.  Then the sequence is $x+(x+11)+(x+2\times 11)+...+(x+39\times 11)=8700$.  Then, the total number of $11$ is $1+2+3+...+39=\frac{39\times 40}{2}=780$.  The sum of these $11$ is then $11\times 780=8580$.  Now we have $40x=8700-8580=120$.  We have $x=3$.  Note that this solution probably isn't very relevant since the question was so long ago, but please accept of it helps.